Sort a Moodle sql pivot query to return highest value for one row
I am using the SQL query below to retrieve some quiz data from a Moodle database.
My test data in the database is:



first name
surname
id number
grade_code
result




Johan
Smith
4432433
148
100%


Johan
Smith
4432433
148
20%


Johan
Smith
4432433
414
96%



As you can see, there are TWO rows containing a result for grade_code 148 (100% and 20%) and ONE row containing a result for grade_code 414 (96%).
The MS SQL Server SQL query that gives me the above test data is:
    SELECT
        u.firstname AS 'first name',
        u.lastname AS 'surname',
        u.idnumber AS 'id number',
        gi.idnumber AS 'grade_code',
        CASE gg.finalgrade
          WHEN NULL THEN 'No result'
          ELSE CAST(CAST(ROUND(((gg.finalgrade/gi.grademax)*100),0) AS INTEGER) AS NVARCHAR(10)) + '%'
        END AS 'result'
    FROM mdl_grade_grades AS gg
    INNER JOIN mdl_grade_items gi ON gg.itemid = gi.id
    INNER JOIN mdl_user u ON gg.userid = u.id
    WHERE gi.idnumber IN (
      '148','414'
    )
    AND u.idnumber = '4432433'

When I pivot the above SQL, like this:
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT
            u.firstname AS 'first name',
            u.lastname AS 'surname',
            u.idnumber AS 'id number',
            gi.idnumber AS 'grade_code',
            CASE gg.finalgrade
              WHEN NULL THEN 'No result'
              ELSE CAST(CAST(ROUND(((gg.finalgrade/gi.grademax)*100),0) AS INTEGER) AS NVARCHAR(10)) + '%'
            END AS 'result'
        FROM mdl_grade_grades AS gg
        INNER JOIN mdl_grade_items gi ON gg.itemid = gi.id
        INNER JOIN mdl_user u ON gg.userid = u.id
        WHERE gi.idnumber IN (
          '148','414'
        )
        AND u.idnumber = '4432433'
    ) SOURCE
    PIVOT (
        MAX(grade)
        FOR grade_code IN (
          [148],[414]
        )
    ) PIVT

the output result I get is:



first name
surname
id number
148
414




Johan
Smith
4432433
20%
96%



The problem is that it is returning the row with 20% for grade_code 148. I want it to return the HIGHEST grade_code (100%), for each grade_code like this:



first name
surname
id number
148
414




Johan
Smith
4432433
100%
96%



So, when there are multiple rows for each grade_code the query must return the one row with the highest value for that grade_code.
Is the fix for this just to find a way to ORDER BY the grade_code column?
My first guess was to add a
ORDER BY '148','414'
to the end of the pivot query, but that is not valid.
Nor is this valid:
ORDER BY [148],[414]
Or this:
ORDER BY grade_code
What do I do to fix this? How to I always return the one highest result for each grade_code?

Seems like your column result is the problem; it's a varchar not a decimal. You need to fix the data type as '1' is less than '2', and thus '20%' is greater than '100%'.

You should perform your grade calculations and pivot operations using a numeric type (not text), leaving the calculated score as calculated (finalgrade/grademax) in the range 0..1. The percentage scaling (x 100) and formatting is best deferred to the presentation layer. or in this case, the final select list since there is no presentation layer.
The null case can be handled using the ISNULL() function.
SELECT
    PIVT.[first name], PIVT.surname, PIVT.[id number],
    ISNULL(CAST(CAST(ROUND(PIVT.[148] * 100, 0) AS INTEGER) AS NVARCHAR(10)) + '%',
           'No result') AS [148],
    ISNULL(CAST(CAST(ROUND(PIVT.[414] * 100, 0) AS INTEGER) AS NVARCHAR(10)) + '%',
           'No result') AS [414]
FROM (
    SELECT
        u.firstname AS [first name],
        u.lastname AS surname,
        u.idnumber AS [id number],
        gi.idnumber AS [grade_code],
        CAST(gg.finalgrade AS FLOAT) / gi.grademax AS fractional_grade
    FROM mdl_grade_grades AS gg
    INNER JOIN mdl_grade_items gi ON gg.itemid = gi.id
    INNER JOIN mdl_user u ON gg.userid = u.id
    WHERE gi.idnumber IN (
      '148','414'
    )
    AND u.idnumber = '4432433'
) SOURCE
PIVOT (
    MAX(fractional_grade)
    FOR grade_code IN (
      [148],[414]
    )
) PIVT

Because I was unsure about your source data types, I added a cast to float before the division in the above calculation.
Results (using some reverse engineered test data):



first name
surname
id number
148
414




Johan
Smith
4432433
100%
96%



See this db<>fiddle for a demo.

Thanks for your effort. I'm testing this on my dev code.

The gi.idnumber - [grade_code] column is a NVARCHAR(255) column. Does that change your query in any way?

No. But if your ID numbers are always integers, your database design would be better if you selected a more appropriate data type, such as INT. Computers a significantly more efficient when processing numbers over character strings.

Thanks. But the ID numbers aren't always integers. Sometimes they contain A-Z letters too, so an INT data type wouldn't work.
